# What Database for extensive logfile analysis?

Tags: sql, database, nosql, analysis, logfile

The task is to filter and analyze a huge amount of logfiles (around 8TB) from a finished research project. The idea is to fill a database with the data to be able to run different analysis tasks later.

The values are stored comma separated. In principle the values are tuples of up to 5 values:

```
id, timestamp, type, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5
```

In a first try using MySQL I used one table with one log entry per row. So there is no direct relation between the log values. The downside here is slow querying of subsets.

Because there is no relation I looked into alternatives like NoSQL databases, and column based tables like hbase or cassandra seemed to be a perfect fit for this kind of data. But these systems are made for huge distributed systems, which we not have. In our case the analysis will run on a single machine or perhaps some VMs.

Which kind of database would fit this task? Is it worth to setup a single machine instance with hadoop+hbase... or is this all a bit over-sized?

What database would you choose to do high-performance logfile analysis?

**EDIT:** Maybe out of my question it is not clear that we cannot spend money for cloud services or new hardware. The Question is if there are benefits in using noSQL approaches instead of mySQL (especially for this data). If there are none, or if they are so small that the effort of setting up a noSQL system is not worth the benefit we can use our ESXi infrastructure and MySQL.

**EDIT2:** I'm still having the Problem here. I did further experiments with MySQL and just inserted a quarter of all available data. The insert is now running for over 2 days and is not yet finished. Currently there are 2,147,483,647 rows in my single table db. With indeces this takes 211,2 GiB of disk space. And this is just a quarter of all logging data...
A query of the form

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `timestamp`>=1342105200000 AND `timestamp`<=1342126800000 AND `logid`=123456 AND `unit`="UNIT40";
```

takes 761 seconds to complete, in this case returning one row.
There is a combined index on timestamp, logid, unit.

So I think this is not the way to go, because later in analysis I will have to get all entries in a time range and compare the datapoints.

I read bout MongoDB and Redis, but the problem with them is, that they are in Memory databases.

In the later analyzing process there will a very small amount of concurrent database access. In fact the analyzing will be run from one single machine.
I do not need redundancy. I would be able to regenerate the database in case of a failure.
When the database is once completely written, there would also be no need to update or add further row.

What do you think about alternatives like Redis, MongoDB and so on. When I get this right, i would need RAM in the dimension of my data...
Is this task even somehow possible with a single node system or with maybe two nodes?

Comment: If you need to do this but don't have the systems for it you could take a look at solutions like Amazon where you can use them for a specified amount of time. That gives you the power to do such big data analyses quite simple and affordable compared to investing in hardware.

Comment: Out of privacy and financial aspects, we can not use such ressources like amazon.

Comment: Ok clear, then the following important question: How much hardware do you have? It's 8TB of data, based on the systems you have we can give a more clear answer. What happens now is that you ask for performance advise but give no info about: systems, performance of them, availability of it (can you use it for days without other users) and about what kind of analysis you want to do. All missing parts which makes it impossible to give good advice. To be clear: You will need some serious memory to let 8TB of data be analyzed. But if you for example can split it our create aggregates it is easier.

Comment: There are several ESXi Servers which can be used, maybe one exclusively (8 Cores 24GB RAM).
The analysis will be something like "give me all log entries where id=x and type=y and timestamp in range of ..." and then we will be looking at the values to analyze project specific parameters.
The exact analyzing questions are to be defined yet. The date should be in a form where we easily can do such analyzes.

Answer (score 0):

well i personally would prefer the faster solution, as you said you need a high-perfomance analysis. the problem is, if you have to setup a whole new system to do so and the performance-improvement would be minor in relation to the additional effort you'd need, then stay with SQL.

in our company, we have a quite small Database containing not even half a GB of Data on the VM. the problem now is, as soon as you use a VM, you will have major performance issues, when opening the Database on VM you can go for a coffee in the meantime ;)

But if the time until the Database is loaded to cache is not so important it doesn't matter. It all depends on how much faster you think the new System will be, and how much effort you will have to put in it, but as i said i'd prefer the faster solution if you have to go for "high-performance analysis"

Comment: The question is: what is the faster solution? I have no experience in noSQL approaches and the performance when not run on distributed systems. Maybe the effort of installing a new noSQL single node server isn't worth the small performance gain.
When saying "high-performance" I mean relatively fast querying in relation to the amount of data.

Comment: i have no experience concerning that either so i just said what i thought. you have to decide yourself either way, and in single node mode i guess both attempts will be quite slow. the faster solution for implementation will obviously be the sql attempt, seen from the point of performance it depends on how often you need to analyse the data. i think it is not reasonable to implement something you are completely new to just to run 10 times and then discard.  [...]

Comment: [...] the more often you analyse, the more time you win by having the faster solution, but you have to think of how long you will need to implement it. and from your description i think it is really some, "do once and never again" task.